# Text/Font scaling on page printing

Tags: c#, scale

I would like to scale a lable/text when printing.

Below is the sample code i am using:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();

g.ScaleTransform(1,2); //scale 200% at Y direction

g.DrawString(myText, myFont, myBrush, pointX, pointY); // pointX = 10; pointY = 5
```

The text is scaled to 200% at Y direction, but the location/point/coordinate of the text is being scale as well.

I want the text to be scaled without changing the pointX and PointY.

How to do that?

Comment: What about changing font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
g.TranslateTransform(pointX, pointY);
g.ScaleTransform(1, 2);
g.TranslateTransform(-pointX, -pointY);

g.DrawString(myText, myFont, myBrush, pointX, pointY);
```

Comment: Great! Also it might help to read a bit more about "Transformation Matrix". Usually you shift the coordinate system toward the center of transformation.